# This is a error I got after images and save URL into database using react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

```
    import React,{ Component } from 'react';
    import Display from '../design/Display';
    import Settings from '../design/Setting';
    import { storage } from '../../config/FirebaseConfig';
    
    class Dashboard extends Component
    {
        state ={
            tshirtColor: 'red',
            url:''
        };
    
        handleImageUpload = (e) =>{
            if(e.target.file[0]){
                const image = (e.target.file[0]);
                const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/images/${image}`).put(image);
                uploadTask.on('state_changed',
                (snapshot) =>{
                    console.log(snapshot);
                },
                (error) =>{
                    console.log(error);
                },
                ()=>{
                    storage.ref('images').child(image.name).getDownloadURL().then(url =>{
                        this.setState({url});
    
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

Here I got uploading errors after selecting image from file. How Can I fix this. Can any one give me to instruction to how avoid from those errors.

Comment: "I got uploading errors after selecting image from file" Please edit your question to include the exact error you get, and (if available) the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at this line very well after creating the "reference" to the image.

```
   const image = (e.target.file[0]);
   const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/images/${image}`).put(image);
```

it should be something like this. You need to create a reference to the image.

```
 const image = (e.target.file[0]);
 const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
```

For more insight, you can check this link out.
[Link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)